# Does JavaScript 'return false' works just inline together with HTML?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I know that JavaScript `return false` means prevent default event (like `preventDefault()` method).

#1

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" onclick="return false;">click</a>
```

#2

```
<a id="a" href="http://stackoverflow.com">click</a>
<script>
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('click', function(){  return false; }, false);
</script>
```

I wonder why just #1 prevent default event but not #2. Did I make some mistake?

Edit:
Sorry, I missed an id of anchor tag and third argument of code in #2. I added it but it's still not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems with your second example:

1. You're using [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.getElementById) but you're giving a tagname. You can probably use [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) (which returns a `NodeList` you would then index into), or give the element an `id` attribute and use `getElementById` to look it up.
2. Your `addEventListener` call is missing the third argument, which is required. So:

   ```
   document.getElementById('someId').addEventListener(
       'click',
       function(){  return false; },
       false // <=== Third argument, you almost certainly want `false`
   );
   ```

Regarding your question about `return false`: If you're using a browser that supports `addEventListener` and you're hooking up event handlers with it, no, you don't use `return false` to prevent the default action. Instead, you use [`event#preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event.preventDefault). (You can also use [`event#stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation) to stop the event bubbling, but DOM0's `return false` doesn't do that, so that's just an extra bonus.)

```
document.getElementById('someId').addEventListener(
    'click',
    function(e){
        // Prevent the default action of the link
        e.preventDefault();

        // Stop the event propagating (bubbling) to the parent element
        e.stopPropagation();
    },
    false
);
```

Also note that there are a lot of people using IE8 and earlier, which **do not support** `addEventListener` (instead, they support Microsoft's original [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); but not all versions support `preventDefault` or `stopPropagation`).

---

**Somewhat off-topic**: As you can see, handling events in a cross-browser way is a hassle. It's one of the many hassles you can avoid by using a decent JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). They smooth over browser differences and provide lots of helpful utility functionality, so you can focus on what you're actually trying to build (rather than worrying about how IE7 and earlier have a [broken version of `getElementById`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html)).

**Examples:**

**jQuery**: jQuery provides a `return false` feature (although it's different from the DOM0 one you're talking about), and it also ensures that `event#preventDefault` and `event#stopPropagation` work regardless of how the underlying browser handles events. So either of these work with jQuery:

```
// Using return false (which prevents the default AND -- unlike DOM0 stuff -- stops propagation)
$('#someId').click(function() { return false; });

// Using the DOM standard event methods -- even on browsers that don't support them
$('#someId').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Prototype**: Prototype provides the DOM standard event methods (even on browsers that don't support them) as well as `event#stop` which is just a combination of preventing the default *and* stopping propagation:

```
// Using `stop` (which prevents the default and stops propagation)
$('someId').observe('click', function(e) { e.stop(); });

// Using the DOM standard event methods -- even on browsers that don't support them
$('someId').observe('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Other libraries will offer similar functionality.

Comment: +1 for the third argument of `addEventListener`, haven't spotted that :)

Comment: Even after I added third argument it still doesn't work. I just wonder why it doesn't work. For example in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/APQk6) if you click the **google**, the page will be redirected.

Comment: @Sangdol: As I said in the answer, if you're using `addEventListener`, you use `event#preventDefault`, not `return false`: http://jsfiddle.net/APQk6/38/ I'll update the answer to make that stronger.

Comment: jQuery's `return false` behaviour is different to `return false` in a DOM0 event handler, which doesn't stop the event propagating. I'd argue that it's an unhelpful feature, and means that *"jQuery makes return false work"* is slightly inaccurate.

Comment: @Tim: Thank you, all these years and I didn't know that (as I've pretty much never written DOM0 handlers). Fixing...

Comment: Do you know of any MDN reference that mentions the inline return false behaviour? Or it just a browser feature that's not mentioned in the spec?

Comment: @user31782 - I don't know about MDN (it's not mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#other_event_listener_mechanisms), but that section consists mostly of "don't use these"), but it's specified [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes). You have to scroll down a fair bit (or search from there for "return value is false"). :-)

Comment: In the *Note* the spec says, _The return value of the function affects whether the event is canceled or not: as described above, if the return value is false, the event is canceled._ but that's not true for **functions**; that's only true for inline js code in the attribute value.

Comment: @user31782 - That section is about event *handlers*, not event *listeners* (apparently this is how the spec differentiates them); the `onclick` attribute in the HTML, or the `onclick` reflected property (including when you assign an actual function to the reflected property). The first line of the section makes that clear. As you say, `return false` has no meaning for listeners attached via `addEventListener`. I did a wrapup of this 11 years ago on my old anemic blog: [*The true story on return false*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html). :-)

Answer (score 3):

This will not work w/o a proper id (not tag name)

```
document.getElementById('a')
```

Try

```
<a id="example" href="http://stackoverflow.com">click</a>
...
document.getElementById('example')...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `getElementById()`, you need an `id` on the element. As the name suggests, this function will find an element by searching for the `id`.

```
<a id="a" href="http://stackoverflow.com">click</a>
<script>
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('click', function(){  return false; });
</script>
```

If you want to find it by tag name, you can use `getElementsByTagName()`. It will return an array (actually a NodeList) of those tags.

Using:

```
var x=document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
```

`x` will store a reference to the first link (`a` element) on the page.

Answer (score 2):

you can't get the anchor-tag with document.getElementById(), because it is a TagName and not an Id.

Comment: addition:
you can get the first tag by using document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0] but thats just an example. you really shouldn't use this, because if you would add an anchor tag before the one you want to use than this would be the first one.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe u have to add "javascript:" before the "return false". Like so:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" onClick="javascript:return false;">click</a>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: no, the `javascript:` scheme makes sense when you use it where you'd use an URL, like in `href` or in the browser address bar. `onclick` is already a script.